# remove text between 2 strings with node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to create a script which should remove some text from a file with node.js.

I have this file:

```
bla bla 
bla bla
<script>
   this text should be
   removed.
export default {
  some stuff here
}
</script>
```

I just want to remove all the text between `<script>` and `export default {`.

Note: I want to keep both `<script>` and `export default }`

Comment: So do you want the valid script to be there and remove invalid data from script tag? Is the `export default { `will be always there?

Comment: I just want to remove everything between <script> and export regardless the correctness of the code. I've seen node.js has a truncate function but I don't know if I'm able to use it in this case.

Answer (score 2):

Regular expression works well

```js
str = str.replace(/(.*\<script\>).*(export.*)/,  '$1$2');
```

*Note:- Read file as a string, synchronously if its big.*

Answer (score 1):

A simple regex matching should suffice:

```
const content = `blah blah
blah blah
<script>
   this text should be
   removed.
export default {
  some stuff here
}
</script>`;

content.replace(/\<script\>([\s\S]*)export/g, '<script>export');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var lineReader = require('readline').createInterface({
    input: require('fs').createReadStream('test_input.txt')
});

const start_marker = '<script>';
const end_marker = 'export default';
var deleteEnabled = false;

lineReader.on('line', function(line) {
    if (!deleteEnabled && line.startsWith(start_marker)) {
        console.log(line);
        deleteEnabled = true;
    } else if (deleteEnabled && line.startsWith(end_marker)) {
        deleteEnabled = false;
    }

    if (!deleteEnabled) {
        console.log(line);
    }
});
```

This will start deleting lines when the start_marker is hit, and stop deleting when the end_marker is hit.